# An object that has a key that matches the key of the supplied object could not be found in the ObjectStateManager

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I Use following code

```
Tel_CallHistory CallHistory = new Tel_CallHistory();


                     CallHistory.MobileNo = MobileNo;
                     CallHistory.CRId = CallResponse;
                     CallHistory.CallRemark = CallRemark;
                     CallHistory.UserId = UserId;
                     CallHistory.CallDate = DateTime.Now;
                     CallHistory.CallTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;

                     CallHistory.MeetingPoint = meetingpoint;
                     if (CallResponse == 1)
                     {
                         CallHistory.NCallDateOn = null;
                         CallHistory.NCallTimeAt = null;
                         CallHistory.MeetingDate = Convert.ToDateTime( meetingdate);

                         CallHistory.MeetingTime =  DateTime.Parse(meetingtime).TimeOfDay;
                     }
                     else
                     {

                         CallHistory.NCallDateOn =  Convert.ToDateTime(NCallDateOn);

                         CallHistory.NCallTimeAt =  DateTime.Parse(NCallTimeAt).TimeOfDay;  

                         CallHistory.MeetingDate = null;
                         CallHistory.MeetingTime = null;
                     }


                     db.Tel_CallHistory.AddObject(CallHistory);


                     Tel_Mobile TelMobile = _teacher.getDB().Tel_Mobile.Single(a => a.MobileNo == MobileNo);
                     TelMobile.CallDate = CallHistory.NCallDateOn;
                     TelMobile.CallTime = CallHistory.NCallTimeAt;

                     TelMobile.LCallDateOn = CallHistory.CallDate;
                     TelMobile.LCallTimeAt = CallHistory.CallTime;
                     TelMobile.LCRId = CallHistory.CRId;
                     TelMobile.LCallRemark = CallHistory.CallRemark;
                     TelMobile.LMeetingPoint = CallHistory.MeetingPoint;
                     TelMobile.LMeetingDate = CallHistory.MeetingDate;
                     TelMobile.LMeetingTime = CallHistory.MeetingTime;

                      db.Tel_Mobile.ApplyOriginalValues(TelMobile);


                     db.SaveChanges();



                     db.AcceptAllChanges();
```

but when `db.Tel_Mobile.ApplyOriginalValues(TelMobile)` executes, show error

> An object that has a key that matches the key of the supplied object
>   could not be found in the ObjectStateManager. Verify that the object
>   to which changes must be applied is not in the Added state and that
>   its key values match the key values of the supplied object.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to attach it.

```
db.Tel_Mobile.Attach(TelMobile);
```